# JS not working after doing custom css on Wordpress Site

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am currently in the process of developing an online shop via wordpress. Everything was working fine, now I wanted to give my page a custom border( inverted round corners) and found the css code for it as seen here:

css:

```
body {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.wrapper {
  overflow:hidden;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;


}

div.inverted-corner {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #3e2a4f;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: solid grey 7px;
}

.top, .bottom {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;

}

.top:before, .top:after, .bottom:before, .bottom:after{
  content:" ";
  position:absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: solid grey 7px;
  border-radius: 20px; 
}

.top:before {
  top:-35px;
  left:-35px;


}

.top:after {
 top: -35px;
 right: -35px;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px grey;
}

.bottom:before {
  bottom:-35px;
  left:-35px;
}

.bottom:after {
 bottom: -35px;
 right: -35px; 
 box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px grey;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="inverted-corner">
<div class="top">&nbsp; </div>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <div class="bottom"> </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

I renamed the classes to get no conflict with the existing css classes of the theme. It is working fine as seen here:[my site](http://kelvin-liebertz.de/). The problem is now, that I cannot interact with the site anymore, no links, no hover effects. It seems like the custom css is overlaying the actual site. Do you have any suggestions what I maybe did wrong?

P.S. I edited the header.php so that inverted corner div and the top div are right underneath the page-wrapper div( site content) and in the footer.php I edited the top div and the inverted-corner div closing right above the page-wrapper div closing.

Comment: The DIV `.bottom-corner` is overlapping all your site. Setting `pointer-events: none;` would fix it but older browsers doesn't support this property.

Comment: @Rob You meant all browsers except IE<11 and opera mini: http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `custom.css` you have this:

```
.top-corner, .bottom-corner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;

}
```

This basically overlays the whole page and thus disables any interaction.

Comment: That's the diagnostic, not the solution :)

Comment: This is a direct answer to the OP question "Do you have any suggestions what I maybe did wrong?"

Comment: Ahh this is actually making sense now :D

Comment: FYI, the cause of such type of issues is easily spotted with the Inspector type tool in your browser's Developer tools. E.g. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/dom-and-styles, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector

Answer (score 6):

Add :

```
pointer-events: none;
```

to the `.bottom-corner` CSS, so the mouse passes through.

Comment: Please note that this will not work on IE10 or lower. http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events

Comment: Oh, I forgot this damn IE. Screw people who still use IE<10.

Comment: Thank you so much. This single line fixed it :D

Comment: Nice :) Please validate the answer if you're happy with it. (The "answer" you validated, for me, is the diagnostic, but it brings no solution at all. It just tells you what you did wrong, but brings no fix. My answer is the fix.)

Answer (score 0):

One other option I would like to suggest to change following css rule

**CSS**

```
.top-corner, .bottom-corner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

**Replace above code with the below one**

```
.top - corner, .bottom - corner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100 % ; 
}
```

this solution will work on all modern browsers and IE8 and above ( I'm not sure about lower version of IE, but it may work on them as well )